# Word for the punishment of sin?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes karmic punishment of a sin committed? Divine punishment.

"*Retribution*" is close but is not "*biblical enough*".

"*Penance*" is close to what I'm looking for, but the punishment needs to be divine and from an external force.

I want to use it like:

> "I did nothing to deserve this *divine retribution*"

I know there is a specific word for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Theomastix***:

> punisher of mortals sent by God; ***such a punishment*** or ***a divine scourge, a cause of wide or great affliction,of mortals*** or a disaster sent by God

Source - [Grandiloquent Dictionary](http://www.islandnet.com/%7Eegbird/dict/t.htm)

***Theomastix***:

> - The scourge of God or appointed by God.
> - When a deity or the deities are thoroughly fed up with mankind, the result is a theomastix. Essentially, the word is a synonym of a plague or a divinely constituted punishment of mortals; such as, the Biblical flood.

Source - [Encyclo,co.uk](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-theomastix)

- Also, you can say they have been sent to ***the pit*** or ***tartarus***.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for ***[anathema](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anathema)***:

> - a formal ecclesiastical curse of excommunication or a formal denunciation of a doctrine.

(Collins)

from which an [atonement](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anathema) may follow:

> - When you apologize for doing something wrong, that’s an act of atonement. Many religions have rituals of atonement, such as Yom Kippur, the Day of Atonement, on which people of the Jewish faith repent for their sins.
> - ***As a religious act, atonement is an effort to make up for wrongdoings so you can be in harmony with a higher power.***  Look closely at the word: you can break it down to "at," "one," and "ment." Atonement first appears in English in the 1510s, when it meant "the condition of being at one (with others)." About ten years later, the word shows up with a meaning that included “being at one with God.”

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: Anathema is really close, but is there a word that means earned anathema?

Comment: @MrPickles7 - well, if an anathema is cast on you it is because you deserved it, at least according to the religious rules you are following.